# Can you make this Key-interable view of a List of Maps better?

Tags: java, list, generics, dictionary, iterator

I have a list of map entries, and I need an iterable that returns the keys of the maps.

Of course, we could be naive and copy over into a new collection of the desired type, but that's inefficient.

So let's see if we can provide a view of the existing structure using generics.  Yes, I was able to do that, but it's not perfect: it gives unchecked conversions when it's passed to a function expecting Iterable<K>.  Could it be improved to avoid these warnings?

Perhaps it could implement Iterable<K> similar to the commented out line which is the path I attempted but couldn't complete.  Can you figure out the similar but correct (no warnings on usage) generic implementation?

This should help demonstrate how the ListKeyIterable is used:

List< Map.Entry < Long,String > > list;

```
void traverse( Iterable<Long> ) {}

traverse( new ListKeyIterable<List<Map.Entry<Long,String>>>( list );
```

Here is the working code, but it gives unchecked conversion warning on the call to traverse().

```
class ListKeyIterable<T extends List<? extends Map.Entry<?,?>>> implements Iterable
//class ListKeyIterable<T extends List<? extends Map.Entry<K,?>>> implements Iterable<K>
{
    T list;

    public ListKeyIterable( T list ) { this.list = list; }

    class ListKeyIterator<K> implements Iterator<K> {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<K,?>> iterator;

        public ListKeyIterator( Iterator<Map.Entry<K,?>> iterator ) { this.iterator = iterator; }
        @Override public boolean hasNext() { return iterator.hasNext(); }
        @Override public K next() { return iterator.next().getKey(); }
        @Override public void remove() { throw new RuntimeException( "ValueListIterator remove() not implemented." ); }
    }

    @Override public Iterator iterator() { return new ListKeyIterator( list.iterator() ); }
    //@Override public <K> Iterator<K> iterator() { return new ListKeyIterator( list.iterator() ); }
}
```

Comment: This might be better-suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why do you use `?` as typename?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
class ListKeyIterable<K,V> implements Iterable<K> {

    List<Map.Entry<K,V>> list;

    public ListKeyIterable(List<Map.Entry<K,V>> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override public Iterator<K> iterator() {
        class ListKeyIterator<K> implements Iterator<K> {
                Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator;

                public ListKeyIterator( Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator ) {
                    this.iterator = iterator;
                }
                @Override public boolean hasNext() {
                    return iterator.hasNext();
                }
                @Override public K next() {
                    return iterator.next().getKey();
                }
                @Override public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "ValueListIterator remove() not implemented." );
                }
        }
        return new ListKeyIterator<K>( list.iterator() );
    }

}
```

Comment: Turns out you don't even need T. You just need K. It's the only truly generic thing in there.

Comment: Also scoped the class to the function. Java provides more encapsulation than you'd ever need or want :-)

Comment: That's very clean!  It looks like it may have one drawback compared to what you had earlier: I saw the intermediate one you had, but didn't try it.  I'd like a look again if you still have that first version.

Comment: This doesn't seem to like concrete types at runtime though, I suppose because all the extends are removed.  I get "inconvertible types" error. "found: java.util.ArrayList<java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Long,java.lang.Integer>>
required: java.util.List<java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Long,?>>"

Comment: Looks like all I really needed was adding K as a parameter to the generic as above.  If you know how to correct your cleaner solution though, I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed the generic to be parameterized by both types, like this:

```
class ListKeyIterable<K,T extends List<? extends Map.Entry<K,?>>> implements Iterable<K>
```